# MessageBodyReader/Writer for Generic class

Tags: java, generics, jersey

I have a class

```
public class Tree<T> {
    private T value;
    private Tree<T> parent;
    private List<Tree<T>> children;
    ...
}
```

I then want to make a MessageBodyReader and Writer to be able to produce and consume JSON that represent instances of this class, but without circular references. So a JSON document would exclude the parent.

I then get a method I shall implement that looks like this

```
@Override
public Tree<?> readFrom(Class<Tree<?>> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
```

How can I determine what ? is in Class<Tree<?>> or in genericType? Or said in other words: How can I determine what kind of object the Tree class is carrying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you're looking for will be stored in `genericType` parameter. The actual type of `genericType` depends on the complexity of the `Tree<T>` hierarchy you're trying to (un)marshall JSON into. Note that the `genericType` is derived (for reader) from resource method signature. For example for a method like:

```
@GET
public String get(final Tree<String> tree) { ... }
```

the `genericType` would contain expected generic type information. But for a method like:

```
@GET
public String get(final Tree tree) { ... }
```

the parameter type of the `Tree` would be `Object`.

**Note:** Instead of (un)marshalling Java Objects into JSON yourself you can use JSON modules that are available in Jersey and try the JAXB approach of JSON<->Object (here you can use the `@XmlTransient` annotation to omit `parent` from (un)marshalling). In Jersey 2.3+ there is also a concept of [entity-filtering](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html) which lets you choose which fields should be considered to be (un)marshalled into/from JSON.

Comment: I do not want any annotations related to serialization or persistence mixed with my domain objects. I'm kinda picky about that - :)

Comment: I guess I will have to add another dependency to my domain-jar and see if that will do the trick.. I am going to test @JsonIgnore annotation. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I have had great success in testing the @JsonIgnore annotation. Now I just need to link to the correct parent after the built-in MessageBodyWriter has done it's job :)